# Are True Type fonts (TTF) standard on Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, .ttf

I know I can use `.ttf` (True Type Font) files on Windows. If I want to install them, I just click on the file and the font gets installed, if it's not already.

I just want to know if:

- Is this the same way on Ubuntu?
- Are `.ttf` files standard to store fonts, or is there another standard on linux?

Answer (score 4):

Fonts can be installed in a system folder (system-specific, for all users) or in a home  (user-specific, for just one user)

System folder: `/usr/share/fonts/`

Home folder: `~/.fonts/` (you may have to create the folder)

Command line utility to refresh the font cache database: `fc-cache -v`

Gnome GUI utility: `gnome-font-viewer`

Ubuntu supports otf and ttf fonts, documented in an another question: [How to install OTF fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18357/how-to-install-otf-fonts?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

[**From wikipeadia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType)

> TrueType is an outline font standard originally developed by Apple
> Computer in the late 1980s as a competitor to Adobe's Type 1 fonts
> used in PostScript. TrueType has become the most common format for
> fonts on both the Mac OS and Microsoft Windows operating
> systems.[citation needed]
>
> The primary strength of TrueType was originally that it offered font
> developers a high degree of control over precisely how their fonts are
> displayed, right down to particular pixels, at various font sizes.
> With widely varying rendering technologies in use today, pixel-level
> control is no longer certain in a TrueType font.

**Linux and other platforms**

> The FreeType project of David Turner attempts to create an independent
> implementation of the TrueType standard (as well as other font
> standards in FreeType 2). FreeType is included in many Linux
> distributions.
>
> There were potential patent infringements in FreeType 1 because parts
> of the TrueType hinting virtual machine were patented by Apple, a fact
> not mentioned in the TrueType standards. (Patent holders who
> contribute to standards published by a major standards body such as
> ISO are required to disclose the scope of their patents, but TrueType
> was not such a standard.) FreeType 2 includes an automatic hinter that
> analyzes glyph shapes and attempts to generate hints automatically,
> thus avoiding the patented technology.[3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu%20Font%20Family) The automatic hinter
> generally improves the appearance of free or cheap fonts, for which
> hinting is often either nonexistent or automatically generated, but it
> can degrade the appearance of professional hand-hinted fonts, and does
> not work well (or at all) for non-Western text that requires a
> different approach to hinting. As a result, some users chose to enable
> the patented hinting technology. As of May 2010, all patents related
> to bytecode hinting have expired worldwide, so FreeType 2.4 now enables these features >by default.

---

**Is this the same way on ubuntu?**

In ubuntu you can install fonts by

1. Open the folder where you have downloaded the font file.
2. Double click on the font file to open it. This opens a font viewer window.
3. On the right there is a button, "Install Font". Click on it.Wait until the button turns to greyed out "Installed".

**Are .ttf files standard to store fonts? Or is there another standard on linux?**

No ,Gnu/linux  uses [free types](http://www.freetype.org/) fonts as default , Ubuntu uses it is own font family  called [ubuntu font family](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu%20Font%20Family), Even then ubuntu supports other ttf fonts very well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, True Type fonts are a standard and are very well-supported in Ubuntu. Ubuntu also supports less common vector font standards such as OpenType (OTF), etc.

IIRC, in Windows you usually right-click a font to Install it; double-clicking opens it in the Font Viewer. Ubuntu does the same -- open in Font Viewer, and click the <kbd>Install</kbd> button to install it:

[image: font-viewer]